# Issue connecting to multiple postgre SQL database using connection string in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a postgre SQL database that has 2 instances of a database as well as a new database; 
 [image]

See Highlighted portion

I am trying to connect my codeigniter application using

```
   "return $conn_string = "hostaddr port dbname=OGSDB user password";
```

The above connection works but if I change it to

```
   "return $conn_string = "hostaddr port dbname=ogsdbdev user password";
```

It fails to connect. I tried creating a new server (dashboard_prd_01192016) but I couldn't differentiate it within the connection string (both dashboard_prd_01192016 and devdb share the same IP and port info) and changing the database name ( ogsdbdev) doesn't work.

My question is, what can I do to either the connection string or the database server so I can connect to either dashboard_prd_01192016.OGSDB or devdb.ogsdbdev.

Thanks for any feedback you can offer

Comment: Show us your DB codes and config as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postgresql process can only run 1 server on the same IP and port at the same time. If you are trying to run 2 different db servers with the same IP and port you will only be able to have 1 running at a time. If "both dashboard_prd_01192016 and devdb share the same IP and port info" then they won't both be running at the same time.